# Nested .each jquery append to class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a nested .each

```
$.each(result.postsViewModel.Posts, function(index, item) {
    $('#postList').append('<div class="col-lg-4 postItem"><div class="ibox"><div class="ibox-content contact-box">' + (item.IsPublic == true ? '<span class="label label-primary pull-right">Public</span>' : '<span class="label label-warning pull-right">Private</span>') + '<a href="@Url.Action("Article", "AppViews")" title="' + item.Title + '" class="btn-link"><h2><span class="postId">' + item.PostId + '</span>. ' + item.Title + '</h2></a><div class="small m-b-xs"><strong>' + item.Category.Name + '</strong> <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' + new Date(parseInt(item.PostedOn.substr(6))) + '</div></div><p>' + $.trim(item.Description.replace(regex, "")).substring(0, 200).trim(this) + '...' + '</p><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 tags"><h5>Tags:</h5></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="small text-right"><h5>Stats:</h5><div><i class="fa fa-comments-o"> </i> 56 comments</div><i class="fa fa-eye"> </i> 144 views</div></div></div><div class="contact-box-custom-footer"><div class="m-t-xs btn-group"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-white deletePostBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove </a></div></div></div></div></div>');

    $.each(item.Tags, function(index, tag) {
        $('.tags').append('<button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button">' + tag.Name + '</button> ');
    });
});
```

**On the second .each append, it's appending to every instance of "tags" class created in the first .each loop in the page**. How do i just let it append to the div i just appended in the first .each?

```
<div class="col-md-6 tags">
```

**Update** This is the final solution, so i guess foreach post in posts, its setting a new variable "var post" and everytime you append now, you only append to this instance of the variable instead of all. thanks all

```
$.each(result.postsViewModel.Posts, function(index, item) {
    var post = $('<div class="col-lg-4 postItem"><div class="ibox"><div class="ibox-content contact-box">' + (item.IsPublic == true ? '<span class="label label-primary pull-right">Public</span>' : '<span class="label label-warning pull-right">Private</span>') + '<a href="@Url.Action("Article", "AppViews")" title="' + item.Title + '" class="btn-link"><h2><span class="postId">' + item.PostId + '</span>. ' + item.Title + '</h2></a><div class="small m-b-xs"><strong>' + item.Category.Name + '</strong> <div class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' + new Date(parseInt(item.PostedOn.substr(6))) + '</div></div><p>' + $.trim(item.Description.replace(regex, "")).substring(0, 200).trim(this) + '...' + '</p><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 tags"><h5>Tags:</h5></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="small text-right"><h5>Stats:</h5><div><i class="fa fa-comments-o"> </i> 56 comments</div><i class="fa fa-eye"> </i> 144 views</div></div></div><div class="contact-box-custom-footer"><div class="m-t-xs btn-group"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-white deletePostBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove </a></div></div></div></div></div>');

    $.each(item.Tags, function (index, tag) {
        post.find('.tags').append('<button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button">' + tag.Name + '</button> ');
    });

    $('#postList').append(post);
});
```

Comment: Are you appending all to 1 div? Is it possible to just give this an ID or not?

Comment: Also, can you please include more HTML in your question, including `#postList`

Comment: On the first .each, i created <div class="col-md-6 tags"> containing all the tags for each post. On the second .each, i append all the buttons into the tags div i've just created, so theres several <div class="col-md-6 tags"> on the page, and for each item.Tags, its appending to every tags div, but i just want it to append to the div i just created, not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to answer your question, you can create a Jquery element and add the buttons to it before you even append it to your DOM:

```
$.each(result.postsViewModel.Posts, function (index, item) {
    var $el = $('<div>Your content</div>');

    $.each(item.Tags, function (index, tag) {
         $el.find('.tags').append('<button class="btn btn-white btn-xs" type="button">' + tag.Name + '</button> ');
    });

    $('#postList').append($el);
});
```

Just mentioning, that it's more performant-wise to create all the nodes and append them together, and not once for every loop iteration.

Comment: Thats not solving my problem, for each of my Posts, i append a class "tags", and then foreach of my post tags, i append the buttons to the "tags" class, so its appending to every instance of tags class, your solution is only allowing me to create an element before hand

Comment: oops, missed the 'tags' class element. fixed it. Is it good now?

Comment: Acutally, you first answer is valid, it shows [object object] for the $el element, changed it to $el.Html(); and it worked, the second edit is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was looking for it